# Typescript: Conditional return type based on arguments props

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function which I want it to return 2 type different types based on its argument props.

```js
interface IPaginateParams {
  perPage: number;
  currentPage: number;
  isFromStart?: boolean;
}

interface IWithPagination<Data, TParams extends IPaginateParams = IPaginateParams> {
  data: Data;
  pagination: IPagination<TParams>;
}

type IPagination<TParams> = TParams extends
  | { currentPage: 1 }
  | { isFromStart: true }
  | { isLengthAware: true }
  ? ILengthAwarePagination
  : IBasePagination;

interface IBasePagination {
  currentPage: number;
  perPage: number;
  from: number;
  to: number;
}

interface ILengthAwarePagination extends IBasePagination {
  total: number;
  lastPage: number;
}

function paginate<TData = any[], TParams extends IPaginateParams = IPaginateParams>(
  options: TParams
): IWithPagination<TData, TParams>;
```

The idea is that if you pass `currentPage: 1` or `isFromStart: true`, it should add 2 additional types to the `pagination` object.

The weird thing is that `IWithPagination` works as expected,

```js
const data = {} as IWithPagination<any, {perPage: 2, currentPage: 1}>;

expectType<ILengthAwarePagination>(data.pagination);
```

But when I use the invocation, it always return the `IBasePagination`

```js
const data = paginate({perPage: 2, currentPage: 1});

expectType<ILengthAwarePagination>(data.pagination) // fails

// or

const data = paginate({perPage: 2, currentPage: 2, isFromStart: true});

expectType<ILengthAwarePagination>(data.pagination) // fails
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAU4HNR0pqOAWwGdkBvAKGWQAdpMsIAuZEAVyICNoBua5AnZQoEcIxZtOPKPxrASAMSgB7IgGUwcKGAD8rLipUAbCHBD8AvpUqhIsRClQB1YGAAWjXGGAqQAHgARPDgAGmQAFQJiMggAD0gQABMyDGxvCGjSZABeNC8QPEztGIA+CgEkkNZgrTk6dMKfP1Y0nCbfAKiS0lKrGzAAT3p8xrxO-27CXtzIrNiEsRSBAB8KQWFRcWxJAEZkaxo18mQFZTVNbTBWMCh2FEPkXTQAGTEsDwBBAHdtYvbxn4BK0AEJwEj-bydfi2cDQeBINBgiEFQEgCo0IQiMRgCSsDjcPgCehQPFSQmyAQwVREfHSIk0MAqOkU-qw+wIpxvEAfdw-P6o5ro+KJFJI8GQjp+DHIJlaYwsmT1Yzg3E7RVE6yUJIQBAq0TIGDsEAIIUNAGQSa1OCzcyDADaAF1wlMYsgRUtUoLitMyHk2hl5qUABQCFS0IUkViu0iUACUrVcHkFEwi1pdQZhlAQfhIYGQg1m5EsyHBaCTnjGQv8dvC5CxWzVTFYu3CJLJACZLKVKIMAHS0KudPtyuDGZAAegnyG+KigAGsSDYcyA88gAF5FktllxuSsWia1igNnGdtsMdXIDvhM40y46G53CDdyjrgdDvwjlTyyfT2cLpds1zfM4lmQcLQgYN602U9L1bOgL2bK9LDjGw4nfA9P1Hccp0NOBgGMJcgA)

Comment: please share `expectType` function

Comment: It is the `expectType` of tsd tests (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsd)

Comment: Could you please share fully reproducable example in TS playground, it will be much easier to help

Comment: The reason is pretty simple - type widening. If you inspect your function call, you will see that the parameter is not a literal, but rather an inferred `{ currentPage: number; perPage: number;}`, obviously, it is not a subtype of `{ currentPage: 1 }` or `{ isFromStart: true }`, but rather a supertype of the first, hence `extends` clause fails and the compiler resolves it to `IBasePagination`. Solution: use `as const` on the literal

Comment: @captain-yossarian - thanks, I also noticed I overstated about the type being a supertype of *both*, which it isn't, of course, already corrected.

Comment: @OlegValter, thank you for the explanation!
Can I put this as const somewhere inside the function definition? these method & types are part of a lib that I'm maintining

Comment: well, I don't think you can force a cast to liter type on the inside. Afaik, only primitive, object and array literals can be asserted as constants, not types. And, frankly, it wouldn't be a good idea - we already lie by saying an object literal is immutable, You can require an explicit annotation, but that's a bit verbose.

Comment: I've tried the Readonly<> utility, didn't worked as well. Maybe you have a different approach to achieve my requirement?

Comment: Readonly of the params worked! thank you @OlegValter

Comment: @felixmosh - hm, didn't think of that, yeah, good idea!

Answer (score 1):

As @OlegValter explained in the comments, when passing an object to `paginate` it inferred as a widen type, for example:

```
{perPage: 2, currentPage: 2, isFromStart: true} // inferred as {perPage: number; currentPage: number; isFromStart: boolean}
```

Therefore, the check in the return type always fallback to the `IBasePagination` type (the else clause).

All we need to do, is to specify that the arguments of the function are `readonly`.

```js
declare function paginate<TData = any[], TParams extends IPaginateParams = IPaginateParams>(
  options: Readonly<TParams>
  // ---------^ this is what made the input as a narrow type
): IWithPagination<TData, TParams>;
```

Working [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAU4HNR0pqOAWwGdkBvAKGWQAdpMsIAuZEAVyICNoBua5AnZQoEcIxZtOPKPxrASAMSgB7IgGUwcKGAD8rLipUAbCHBD8AvpUqhIsRClQB1YGAAWjXGGAqQAHgARPDgAGmQAFQJiMggAD0gQABMyDGxvCGjSZABeNC8QPEztGIA%20CgEkkNZgrTk6dMKfP1Y0nCbfAKiS0lKrGzAAT3p8xrxO-27CXtzIrNiEsRSBAB8KQWFRcWxJAEZkaxo18mQFZTVNbTBWMCh2FEPkXTQAGTEsDwBBAHdtYvbxn4BK0AEJwEj-bydfi2cDQeBINBgiEFQEgCo0IQiMRgCSsDjcPgCehQPFSQmyAQwVREfHSIk0MAqOkU-qw%20wIpxvEAfdw-P6o5ro%20KJFJI8GQjp%20DHIJlaYwsmT1Yzg3E7RVE6yUJIQBAq0TIGDsEAIIUNAGQSa1OCzcyDADaAF1wlMYsgRUtUoLitMyHk2hl5qUABQCFS0IUkVgAJTMST8xkGkyDlAAlK1XB5BRMItaXUGYZQEH4SGBkINZuRLMhwWhM54xkL-HbwuQsVs1UxWLtwiSyQAmSylSiDAB0tEbnVHcrgxmQAHp58hviooABrEg2YsgUvIABelertZcbgbFomLYo7ZxA97DHVyH74TONMuOhudwgQ8oe-Hk7804qPKC5Liu66bkWJZlnEswThaEDBm2mw3g%20PZ0PeXaPpYqY2HEf7ngBM5zouhpwMAxibkAA)